# Can I monitor multiple dropdowns for changes without writing a JavaScript function for each one?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm hoping there is a way to add more dropdowns as my site expands without adding more and more functions to the JavaScript. Is there a way to do this?

I can add more functions to the JavaScript like so:

```
        $(".dropDownTwo").focusout(function () {
        $(".dropDownThree").focusout(function () {
        $(".dropDownFour").focusout(function () {
```

But I was hoping to reuse the same function for multiple dropdowns.

Here is my dropdown:

```
                        <div class="col-md">
                            @{
                                var dropDownOneDropdown = Dropdown.GetList();
                            }
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemOne, dropDownOneDropdown, "--SELECT--", new { @class = "form-control dropDownOne" })
                        </div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropDownOne").focusout(function () {
                var variable = $(".dropDownOne").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
                    data: { variable: variable },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (response) {
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function () { }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Method(string variable)
{
    do work here

    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from having them all use the same class name?

Comment: When I use the same class name for all of my dropdowns, the variable that is passed is from the wrong dropdown. It isn't from the one being modified, but from the first one on the screen. I do like this approach but it doesn't seem like it's behaving in a usable way, am I doing something wrong and it should work?

Comment: Make sure if you're replying someone, you use the @username syntax. By default, only the person who created the post gets notified. Luckily I checked back in my comment history and noticed that you had left this comment. As for your issue with using the same class name for all of them - that's only to wire up the focusout event. For grabbing the value of the dropdown, you'll probably need to do some $(this) magic to refer to the dropdown the actually triggered the event, that way you're not grabbing the value from the first dropdown.

Comment: @mason Sorry! Thank you checking back. I think I got it working using $(this), so thank you for the help! I'll post an answer. I knew there had to be some way to reference it that I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mason for the help. Below is working for me as I was hoping.

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".documentStatus").focusout(saveDocument);
    });
    function saveDocument () {
        var documentType = $(this).attr("name");
        var statusCd = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
            data: { documentType: documentType, statusCd: statusCd },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () { }
        });
    };
</script>
```

HTML/Dropdowns:

```
<div class="col-md">
@{
    var dropDownOneDropdown = Dropdown.GetList();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemOne, dropDownOneDropdown, "--SELECT--", new { @class = "form-control documentStatus" })
```

```
<div class="col-md">
@{
    var dropDownTwoDropdown = Dropdown.GetList();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemTwo, dropDownTwoDropdown, "--SELECT--", new { @class = "form-control documentStatus" })
```